# How to export data to CSV using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv, download, get

I have managed to write a script to export data from a GET request in Javascript to CSV. However I have a `unit` variable that has more fields (time, altitude, latitude, o3, co2, ch2o). How can I create a CSV with more columns with the values taken from the script?

So far I have managed to create a CSV with multiple headers, but I don't know how to populate the rows of the CSV with data. I have managed to fully populate only one column.

In the below function, I have used `unit[Object.keys(unit)[4]]` to only get `co2` data. How can I append data to every column?

```js
function download_csv(data, sensor) {
  var csv = 'Day, altitude, latitude, o3, co2, ch2o\n';
  for (var index in data) {
    if (!data.hasOwnProperty(index)) continue;
    var unit = data[index];
    csv += unit[Object.keys(unit)[4]];
    csv += "\n";
  }
  var hiddenElement = document.createElement('a');
  hiddenElement.href = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(csv);
  hiddenElement.target = '_blank';
  hiddenElement.download = sensor + '.csv';
  hiddenElement.click();
}
```

Data has this format:
[image]

Comment: Can you give an example for `data`?

Comment: @wederer I have updated the question with an image of the data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming the `data` argument contains an array of objects which you use to build the CSV data, you can use `Object.keys()` and `Object.value()` to dynamically build the data. Using this method it does not matter what the key names are, or how many of them is contained in the data.

```js
function download_csv(data, sensor) {
  let csvHeader = Object.keys(data[0]).join(',') + '\n'; // header row
  let csvBody = data.map(row => Object.values(row).join(',')).join('\n');

  var hiddenElement = document.createElement('a');
  hiddenElement.href = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(csvHeader + csvBody);
  hiddenElement.target = '_blank';
  hiddenElement.download = sensor + '.csv';
  hiddenElement.click();
}

let data = [{
  lorem: 'ipsum',
  foo: 'bar',
  fizz: 'buzz'
}];
download_csv(data, 'foobar');
```

One thing to note if you need to support legacy browsers is that `Object.values` is unsupported in IE. There is a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values#Polyfill) available, though.